# Add fields to mongoose aggregation dynamically based on req params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an API where 3 input parameters can be specified, such as:
`/trips/:id/:from/:to`. The parameters I am interested in especially are `from` and `to`. In my mongoDB collection, I have a structure like the following:

```
id    2014_08     2014_09     ...
1     [...]       [...]
2     [...]       [...]
```

Now what I want to achieve in the following aggregation, is that based on what is requested from the call in `from` and `to`, it should return the corresponding fields.

For example: `GET /trips/1/2014_08/2014_09` should return:

```
id: 1,
2014_08: {
    ...
},
2014_09: {
    ...
}
```

My route looks like this:

```
app.get('/trips/:id/:from/:to', function(req,res) {
    var aggr = Trip.aggregate([
        {   "$match": {
                "_id": Number(req.params.id)
            }
        },{
                "$project": {
                "_id"  : 1,
                "trips_201408": "$2014_08",
                //How to append more to this, according to from/to?
            }
        }
    ])
        aggr.options = { allowDiskUse: true };
        aggr.exec(function(err, trips){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(trips); 
    });
});
```

So my question is, what a good practice for creating project stages dynamically corresponding to the input of from and to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is just a plain JavaScript object

```
var project = { };

project['trips_' + req.params.from] = 1;
project['trips_' + req.params.to] = 1;

var aggr = Trip.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": Number(req.params.id) } },
  { "$project": project }
])
```

Also the `_id` is always implied.

---

Or with looping a range:

```
var from = new Date(req.params.from.split('_').join('-')+'-01');
var to = new Date(req.params.to.split('_').join('-')+'-01');

var project = { };

for ( var d = from; d <= to; d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1) ) {
  project['trips_' + d.getUTCFullYear() + '_' + 
    ( (d.getUTCMonth() + 1 < 10) 
      ? '0' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) 
      : (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) )] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Neat, thanks! This way makes bulding the query much easier. Just need a loop now when more than 2 consecutive months are specified.

Comment: @ffritz Sure. That's simple enough. Added.

Comment: Oh nice, wasn't expecting that but working on my own solution. This looks great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Small remark: Should be `d.getUTCMonth() + 1` or something like this, as `getUTCMonth()` returns 0 for January up until 11 for December. So in this context 1 short.

Comment: @ffritz Good catch. I was on autopilot there and forgot to add it.